# AWS PHP SDK Cloudfront Cookies Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm having trouble getting code from AWS' PHP SDK to work. The code can be found here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/cloudfront-signed-url.html?highlight=cookie

Obviously in my own case I've updated the resource key, paths to keys and so on but haven't done this for the below example. Essentially all I have added to their code is add the function name and the opening an closing brackets for the function. The SDK requires is elsewhere in my code.

However the below returns "syntax error, unexpected end of file" but I can't I work out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
protected function cookieAWSSDK1()
    {

$cloudFront = new Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient([
'region'  => 'us-west-2',
'version' => '2014-11-06'
]);

// Setup parameter values for the resource
$resourceKey = 'https://example-distribution.cloudfront.net/videos/example.mp4';
$expires = time() + 300;

$customPolicy = <<<POLICY
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Resource": "{$resourceKey}",
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {"AWS:SourceIp": "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/32"},
            "DateLessThan": {"AWS:EpochTime": {$expires}}
        }
    }
]
}
POLICY;

// Create a signed cookie for the resource using a custom policy
$signedCookieCustomPolicy = $cloudFront->getSignedCookie([
'policy' => $customPolicy,
'private_key' => '/path/to/your/cloudfront-private-key.pem',
'key_pair_id' => '<cloudfront key pair id>'
]);

foreach ($signedCookieCustomPolicy as $name => $value) {
setcookie($name, $value, 0, "", "example-distribution.cloudfront.net", true, true);
}
}
```

Comment: On what line are you getting that error?

Comment: Always the last line.

Comment: On further inspection it seems to be an error in my wider code as copying and pasting the above into my editor in isolation and then adding php opening and closing tags doesn't produce an syntax error.

Comment: The syntax error appears when this section of code is added

Comment: // Setup parameter values for the resource
$resourceKey = 'https://example-distribution.cloudfront.net/videos/example.mp4';
$expires = time() + 300;

$customPolicy = <<<POLICY
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Resource": "{$resourceKey}",
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {"AWS:SourceIp": "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/32"},
            "DateLessThan": {"AWS:EpochTime": {$expires}}
        }
    }
]
}
POLICY;

Comment: Try removing this "<<<" and then give it a try

Comment: @error2007s `<<<` is the [heredoc operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heretic).

Comment: I found a solution to this but it was a workaround to say the least. I used completely different bit of code which can be found here https://www.strehle.de/tim/weblog/archives/2015/11/06/1575